# How to clone a public GitHub repository recursively without authentication?

Tags: git, github

I am trying to deploy an application from GitHub into a test server. I have created a new user in the server to own the local repository and run the application. Later on this user should also perform a daily pull from the repository automatically.

I am able to run a simple `git clone` from the repository with this new user. However, when I try to get all its sub-modules (`git clone --recursive`) I get this error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Clone of 'git@github.com:organisation/submodule.git' into submodule path 'submodule' failed
```

All the sub-modules are also public repositories at GitHub, that I am able to clone individually to the server with this new user. Why can't they be cloned as sub-modules?

Comment: Did you try running git clone, git submodule init, git submodule update? That should be equivalent of git clone --recursive.

Comment: Did you created a ssh key for the newly created user and added it the key to github?

Comment: I tried `git submodule init` and then `git submodule update` - I get the exact same error in the last command. It is like GitHub (or `git` ?) is treating sub-modules as private repositories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your submodule is configured to clone using `git:` - update `.gitmodules` to reference the `https:` URL instead. Change:

`git@github.com:organisation/submodule.git`

to

`https://github.com/organisation/submodule.git`

Comment: Your initial repo clone might be, but your output shows that the submodule is configured to use `git`. You may need to update the `.gitmodules` file in the parent repo.

Comment: Modifying the `.gitmodules` file is the solution. Could you correct your answer so I can accept it?